# CSAPP iterative echo server&client code

Tags: c

Are there someone who studied CSAPP iterative echo server code?

I'm sorry that I cannot provide you a full code..

```
Rio_written(clientfd, buf, strlen(buf));
Rio_readlineb(&rio, buf, MAXLINE);
```

in this client code, why why we can write like this? I mean 
does this code ensures sequence of writing and reading from the server?